# Can I have my webservice client in same project as my webservice (NetBeans)

Tags: web-services, netbeans, jax-ws

Is it possible to have my webservice client in the same project as my webservice?

When I try and build the project, NetBeans cant find a reference to the WSDL as it is not deployed.

What is the approved way of doing this?

WulfgarPro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

Just needed to add the *eventual* url of the web-service in **web/WEB-INF/wsdl/mywsdlfile.wsdl** where it stipulates:

`<soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>`

Doing this, then clean-build and deploy, fixed all my problems. Now I have both my service and client running in the same project.

I'm not liking that NetBeans has so many property/configuration files. Seems to me that NetBeans is trying to do too much.

WulfgarPro

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to have a service and its client in the same ant based NetBeans project as created by NetBeans.  You could probably hack the build.xml to make it possible... but I do not know the details of the hacking necessary to make it possible.